# VHDL component and outputs based on generic

Tags: vhdl

I have a system consisting out of several components that has to be attached to a bus. However to keep the system bus independent, I gave the system a generic bus port that I run through a bus specific module that translates between my system and a specific bus. Thus it is easy to connect the entire system to different buses by switching the translating module.

However I don't want to go through the hassle of connecting the system with the translation module every time. Thus I wonder if it is possible to instantiate a module from a generic parameter, and use its types for the outputs of the architecture.

The whole becomes clearer with a little illustration, my translator modules have the following "signature".

```
entity translate<BusName>
port(toSystem: out toSystem_t,
  fromSystem: in fromSystem_t,
  toBus: out to<BusName>_t,
  fromBus: in from<BusName>_t
end entity;
```

I now want to build an entity containing the system and a translator, based on a generic, somewhat like so:

```
entity entireSystem is
  generic(busType := translate<BusName>)
  port(toBus: out to<BusName>_t,
       fromBus: in from<BusName>_t)
end entity

architecture genArc of entireSystem is
   signal toTrans: fromSystem;
   signal fromTrans: toSystem;
begin
   system: system(toTrans,fromTrans)
   translator: translate<BusName>(
       fromTrans,
       toTrans,
       toBus,
       fromBus
   )
end architecture;
```

My problems are:
Can I use a generic parameter to directly instantiate a component, or do I have to go the `if generic=xxx generate` path? Can I derive the type of ports from a generic parameter.
It would be best if I can use one generic parameter to determine the ports and the entity, so that one can not pick wrong types for an entity by accidents. It would be fine to derive the types from the generic parameter with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, no.

If you want to instantiate different things based on a generic, you have to use `if..generate`.

The only influence that generics can have on the types of ports is that of changing the width.  You can't switch between (say) an `integer` and a `boolean` based on a generic.

Comment: I was afraid so,... Just wanted to make sure i don't miss out on a cool new feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I use a generic parameter to directly instantiate a component, 
or do I have to go the if generic=xxx generate path?
```

You can use the `generic map` syntax in module instantiation to pass the bus size to your sub-components. i.e.:

```
u_system: system
generic map ( INPUT_WIDTH => INPUT_WIDTH, OUTPUT_WIDTH => OUTPUT_WIDTH )
port map    ( ... )
```

In the top level, you will need to have two generics instead of one.

Alternatively, assuming that your top level component must have the same bus size as your sub-components, you can try to do this in a package file and define the bus size by using function call. i.e.:

```
package pack is
  -- # Define support bus name here 
  constant BusA    : integer := 0;
  ...
  constant BusZ    : integer := 25;

  -- # Bus name here
  constant busname : integer := BusA;

  -- # Input and Output Width
  constant IWIDTH  : integer := getIWIDTH( busname )
  constant OWIDTH  : integer := getOWIDTH( busname )

  -- # Function declaration
  function getIWIDTH( ii: integer ) return integer;
  function getOWIDTH( ii: integer ) return integer;
end pack;

package body pack is
  function getIWIDTH( ii: integer ) return integer is
     variable oo : integer;
  begin
     -- # get iwidth here            
     return oo;
  end function;
  function getOWIDTH( ii: integer ) return integer is
     variable oo : integer;
  begin
     -- # get owidth here
     return oo;
  end function;
end package body;
```

Comment: The problem I have is slightly different. First of all usually there is a record defined for buses, containing the `data` and several `control signals`. This is achievable in `vhdl2008` with `type generics`. What I wanated to know was if I could pass my Toplevel a generic parameter `AHB` and based on that initiate a component that handels the `AHB`-bus and define the inputs and outputs of the systems of the according types (`AHB_master_in/out` records). I was asking somthing similar to your question: Can I write a function like `busOutRecord(bus) return recordType` to use in a type generic

Comment: The function should return a `recordType`, not an integer (I know how to do that)